# Long time to build apk via gradle.

Tags: java, android, gradle, rx-java, retrolambda

I am working on an Android project, using gradle for building. Also we have different libraries like RxJava, Retrolambda, HttpOk and few more.

My issue is the build time to build apk is somewhere around 3.x min which is quite pain for development like you have to wait for 3 min doing nothing.

Is there any solution for this???

P.S- using: gradle --offline --daemon <--command--> to build Apk.

(I feel like retolambda is taking too much time to convert java8->java7)

Comment: Which Android Studio version are you using? Which gradle plugin version and which gradle wrapper version?

Comment: Android Studio 1.5.1
Gradle 2.3

Comment: Gradle 2.3 is very old. I would use at least 2.10 or even 2.11.

Comment: i can try but i dont think this will solve the problem. Problem is with retrolambda.